# html code after render partial doesn't display

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 5 on my project.

I have a `home_controller` with `index` action. In the index view i render a partial(`_stories.html.erb`) but the code after partial doesn't display, seems some times if i get back from some page it shows up.

What's the issue here?

And if i want to make `index.html.erb` (home page) with some layout parts, what's the correct way? Is render different partials in `index.html.erb'?

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial => 'stories/stories' %>
<!-- The code below doesn't show up -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's in your `_stories.html.erb` partial, if the modal code works everywhere else, then it's probably something wrong in the partial

Comment: @lusketeer Thanks, i redirect to wrong url!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue, I redirect to wrong path so the after code didn't show up!